# How do I interact with structures in arraylists?

Tags: vb.net, arraylist, structure

I need help trying to learn how to make structures work with arraylists. I am trying to make a program that allows a user to input an account. This is for a homework assignment and the prof wants to use arraylists instead of list.

The account includes a first name, last name, account number, and balance. The user can use the previoous and next buttons to page through the accounts, and use the new, save, and add buttons to create, or change accounts. I am mostly curious how I cycle throughout the arraylist, and how I call a certain variable from the structure at a certain index. For example, I want to display the first name in the firstnametextbox. When I press "Next" button, how do I make FirstNameTextbox.Text = 'First name of the account structure, in the 2nd arraylist spot'

Here is my code

http://ideone.com/s1DlGn

Public Class AccountInformationForm

```
Dim objaccount As account
Dim accounts As New ArrayList

Public Structure account

    Public RecordNum As Integer
    Public FirstName As String
    Public LastName As String
    Public balance As Double
    Public account As Integer
End Structure

Private Sub AccountInformationForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Example account to start off with
    objaccount.RecordNum = 0
    objaccount.FirstName = "Jesus"
    objaccount.LastName = "Christ"
    objaccount.balance = 100
    objaccount.account = 1

    accounts.Add(objaccount)


    'Display First Record
    firstTextBox.Text = objaccount.FirstName
    lastTextBox.Text = objaccount.LastName
    balanceTextBox.Text = objaccount.balance
    accountTextBox.Text = objaccount.account



End Sub


Private Sub nextButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nextButton.Click


    objaccount.RecordNum += 1

    If objaccount.RecordNum > accounts.Count Then
        objaccount.RecordNum = 0

    End If


    'Display Current Record
    firstTextBox.Text = objaccount.FirstName
    lastTextBox.Text = objaccount.LastName
    balanceTextBox.Text = objaccount.balance
    accountTextBox.Text = objaccount.account
End Sub


Private Sub previousButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles previousButton.Click
    'Before paging away, save the current form data in the current record

    objaccount.RecordNum -= 1

    'Check for wrap around
    If objaccount.RecordNum < 0 Then 'the first, zeroth, element = index of 0
        objaccount.RecordNum = accounts.Count



    End If


    firstTextBox.Text = objaccount.FirstName
    lastTextBox.Text = objaccount.LastName
    balanceTextBox.Text = objaccount.balance
    accountTextBox.Text = objaccount.account




End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    Dim upper As Integer = accounts.Count
    objaccount.RecordNum = (upper + 1)



    If firstTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a name")
    Else
        objaccount.FirstName = firstTextBox.Text
    End If

    If lastTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a name")
    Else
        objaccount.LastName = lastTextBox.Text
    End If

    If balanceTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a name")
    Else
        objaccount.balance = balanceTextBox.Text
    End If

    If accountTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a name")
    Else
        objaccount.account = accountTextBox.Text
    End If

    accounts.Add(objaccount)


    firstTextBox.Clear()
    lastTextBox.Clear()
    balanceTextBox.Clear()
    accountTextBox.Clear()

End Sub

Private Sub Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Save.Click




    Dim upper As Integer = accounts.Count
    objaccount.RecordNum = (upper + 1)


    If firstTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a name")
    Else
        objaccount.FirstName = firstTextBox.Text
    End If

    If lastTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a name")
    Else
        objaccount.LastName = lastTextBox.Text
    End If

    If balanceTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a name")
    Else
        objaccount.balance = balanceTextBox.Text
    End If

    If accountTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a name")
    Else
        objaccount.account = accountTextBox.Text
    End If

    accounts.Add(objaccount)


End Sub

Private Sub btnNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNew.Click
    firstTextBox.Clear()
    lastTextBox.Clear()
    balanceTextBox.Clear()
    accountTextBox.Clear()


    Dim upper As Integer = accounts.Count
    objaccount.RecordNum = (upper + 2)
    accountTextBox.Text = objaccount.RecordNum

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: The best way is to replace the structure with a Class and the ArrayList with a `List(Of T)`

Comment: Use a [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, `ArrayList`s are outdated.

Comment: Sorry to be clear, this is for a homework assignment which the prof wants me to use the arraylist and structure. I made it work with List as I saw from googling that arraylist is outdated.

Comment: That´s exactly why our education system doesn´t prepare for real life...sorry for off-topic

Comment: Have the prof read [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx) while you browse [Ask] and the [Tour]

Comment: On-Topic: Have you read some [tutorial](https://www.dotnetperls.com/arraylist-vbnet) about ArrayList?

Comment: Dont go by the recordnumber to know if you have gone too far. Use the `.Count` property of the array list...otherwise, how does what you have not work?  whats the problem?

Comment: I have read that tutorial and others, it helps me to understand how to add and view single variables to an arraylist, but not a structure. How do I call a certain variable from a structure at a certain index of the arraylist?

Comment: `firstTextBox.Text = accounts(index).FirstName`

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks, that was what I was looking for, it worked. I couldn't figure out that syntax.

Comment: note that it is the Index not the `RecordNum` which is of no use in navigating or selecting records

Comment: @Plutonix Got it, thanks. That was more so left over from doing the same program with arrays before.